# Multiple tabs in single excel

Tags: python

I am using below code to create a single excel with multiple tab based on the csv files present on path. I have two files in my path. so instead of getting two tabs in a single excel getting one tab with blank. Please help me to fix this code.

```
import os
import glob
import xlsxwriter
import csv
import pandas
path='/axp/buanalytics/csgsn/dev/GSN/VGEN_Files/Test/Tulu/VG/Data/'
flist = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(os.getcwd() + '/axp/buanalytics/csgsn/dev/GSN/VGEN_Files/Test/Tulu/VG/Data/*.csv')]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('/axp/buanalytics/csgsn/dev/GSN/VGEN_Files/Test/Tulu/VG/Data/split_book.xlsx')

for sh in flist:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sh)
    with open(sh, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Three problems:

1) flist = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(os.getcwd() + '/axp/buanalytics/csgsn/dev/GSN/VGEN_Files/Test/Tulu/VG/Data/*.csv')]

Assuming that os.getcwd() is the same as your path, you will end up with the pathname twice.  This means that flist will be empty.  Since you have gone through the trouble of setting path, why not just

```
flist = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(path + '*.csv')]
```

2) Same as above

```
workbook = path + 'split_book.xlsx'
```

3) The file should be opened as a text file

```
with open(sh, 'r') as f
```

Try that and your program should work.  You don't need pandas for this - is that for later?

Comment: Could you please edit my code and share complete code with me?

Comment: I have edited my code as per your comments but getting one tab with blank.

Comment: Did you understand the answer?

Comment: Can you print flist - how many items are you getting.  Also print sh after each open.

Answer (score 0):

Read the files using pandas and combine all of them

```
import os
import pandas as pd

csv_names = [files for files in os.listdir("Your Directory/")]    #get names of csv files in directory "Directory/"

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Multiple Workbooks.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for files in csv_names:
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join("Your Directory",files)) #read csv file
    filename = files[:-4]                                  #remove ".csv" from filename
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=filename)              #add to workbook

writer.save()
```

In short you can add a tab to an dataframe using

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Multiple Workbooks.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="SheetName")
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="SheetName2")
```

Comment: How can I create df1 and df2 df using for loop? Let me explain my question again: i have two csv files(1.csv,2.csv) having some records each. I want to create one excel(output.xlsx) with having two tab named as 1 and 2 based on the csv file name and also whatever records present in csv files shd be present in excel.

Comment: So you just want to combine the csv into one file with different tabs?

Comment: Changed the code to read any number of files in the directory "Your Directory" and add them into single excel file with same name as csv file.

Comment: So you just want to combine the csv into one file with different tabs? Yes but no idea what will be the code. Could you please help me on that?

Comment: @TuluSahoo I edited the code please check it.It will add any number of csv files in the directory.

Comment: I ran the code you provided with my directory but it did not create any o/p excel file in my path.

Comment: It will create the file where the code is placed. Was there any error You can give the outout dir path before `Multiple Workbooks.xlsx` @TuluSahoo

Comment: Thanks, Now able to get the output. only one problem right now is my csv file name like file1.csv,file2.csv..In excel im getting file1. and file2.---how can i remove dot from the excel tab.

Comment: Changed code line from `filename = files[:-3]` to `filename = files[:-4]` check the changes @TuluSahoo